# How to delete something from an Array using GET

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, get, array-splice

The code below is supposed to delete something from an Array from a JSON file by using GET. However, no matter what number is inputted it just goes to the else statement displaying the error message. I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong as no errors are showing in the console either.

The objective of this code is to delete the element from the array which is the same as the ID of the element in the JSON file. So if the get request is `delete/02` it should delete the element with the Id 02 in the array, not the third element in the array.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var rawData = fs.readFileSync('toDoList.json');
var tasksArray = JSON.parse(rawData);
console.log(list);



app.get('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {

 for (var i = 0; i < tasksArray.length; i++) {

   if(tasksArray[i]["id"] == req.params['id']) {

    tasksArray.splice([i], 1);

    var json = JSON.stringify(tasksArray);
    fs.writeFileSync("toDoList.json", json, "utf8");
    res.json(tasksArray);

    console.log[i];

    }

    else {
    res = res.status(500);
    res.json({"status": "error"});
   }

  break;

 }

});
```

Here is the JSON if it is any help:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "01",
    "desc": "Assignment 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "02",
    "desc": "Assignment 2"
  },
  {
    "id": "03",
    "desc": "Assignment 3"
  },
  {
    "id": "04",
    "desc": "Assignment 4"
  },
  {
    "id": "05",
    "desc": "Assignment 5"
  }
]
```

Comment: is not tasksArray.splice(i, 1)?

Comment: there are many error logic: `tasksArray.splice([i], 1);` --> why an array with `i`? If you want to remove 05, the first if statemant will be `01 == 05 ?`--> `res.status 500`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer a basic filter:

```js
var tasksArray = [
  {
    "id": "01",
    "desc": "Assignment 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "02",
    "desc": "Assignment 2"
  },
  {
    "id": "03",
    "desc": "Assignment 3"
  },
  {
    "id": "04",
    "desc": "Assignment 4"
  },
  {
    "id": "05",
    "desc": "Assignment 5"
  }
];

var id_to_delete = "02";

var remainingTasks = tasksArray.filter( task => task.id !== id_to_delete );

// write remainingTasks back into the JSON file as before.
console.log( remainingTasks );
```

As per the comment `.splice( i, 1 );` should work as well.

PS: I would prefer id to be an actual number instead of a string. That will help with sorting and you do not have to check if you need to prepend 0s when adding an item, just the current length + 1 equals the next id.

```js
//var fs = require('fs');
//var rawData = fs.readFileSync('toDoList.json');
//var tasksArray = JSON.parse(rawData);
var tasksArray = [
  { "id": "01", "task": "do 1" },
  { "id": "02", "task": "do 2" },
  { "id": "03", "task": "do 3" },
  { "id": "04", "task": "do 4" },
  { "id": "05", "task": "do 5" }
];

console.log( tasksArray );

//app.get('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {

  //var id_to_delete = req.params.id;
  var id_to_delete = "02";
  
  var remainingTasks = tasksArray.filter( task => {
    if ( task.id === id_to_delete ) {
      console.log( 'filtering away task with id: ' + task.id );
      console.log( task );
      return false;
    }
    else return true;
  });
  // Doublecheck that exactly one item was removed.
  if ( remainingTasks.length === tasksArray.length - 1 ) {
    var json = JSON.stringify( remainingTasks );
    // fs.writeFileSync("toDoList.json", json, "utf8");
    // res.json( remainingTasks );
    console.log( json );
  }
  else {
    //res = res.status(500);
   //res.json({"status": "error"});
    console.log( 'error' );
  }

// });
```

Comment: And radonirina commented `.splice( i, 1 )`, so I'm just confirming that that is the correct way to write the splice.

Comment: I realised the splice error, but I want to make it so that the parameter in the Get request is the id which is deleted

Comment: Hence i suggest using `Array.filter()` instead of recreating array.filter() with a for-loop yourself. Then you don't have to mess with `i`, or fixing the break, or fixing the else clause that will always throw an error. etc. If you want to double check the id or something, you can write the filter function as follows: `task => { if ( task.id === id_to_delete ) { console.log task ); return false; else return true; }`.

Comment: I've added an example using your variable names and such.

Comment: I have a question about the `if (task.id == id_to_delete)` What is the value of task.id because it hasn't been assigned anything?

Comment: It is defined before the arrow: `tasksArray.filter( task => { ... });`. Its equivalent to: `tasksArray.filter(function( task ) { ... });`. So `task` is the parameter of the function. It's also almost equivalent to: `for ( var i = 0, length = taskArray.length; i < length; i++ ) { var task = taskArray[i]; }`. The difference is that you dont have to declare `i`, you don't have to declare `length`, you don't have to redeclare `task` every time. You don't have issues with `break`. So for i 0, task equals `{ "id": "01", "task": "" }`, for i 1 task equals `{ "id": "02", "task": "" }` and so on.